# how to save state of the page when refreshing? (HTML, JS)

Tags: javascript, html

***(DISCLAIMER:** I'm new to coding so my code probably isn't optimal. If you know a better way to do it, feel free to leave it in the comments **)***

Most of the time I had no idea what I was doing, but with patience and with you guys' help I came up with this:

```
if (window.localStorage) {

// Create the Key/Value 
var cNum = localStorage.getItem("currentNumber");

if (localStorage.currentNumber == undefined) {
  localStorage.setItem("currentNumber","0");}
    
// Variables
resetCount.innerHTML = localStorage.currentNumber;

// Functions
function btnR() {
    cNum++;
    localStorage.currentNumber = cNum;
    resetCount.innerHTML = cNum;}}
```

else { console.log("No"); }

HTML:

```
<button id="resetButton" onclick="btnR()">Reset</button>
        <p id="resetCount">0</p>
```

I was creating a button that each time you click on it, it reset the checkboxes, but I also wanted a counter to see how many times they got rested. The problem was that every time I click the button the counter also reset. Now that is solved I can try to apply the same thing for the checkboxes, so they don't reset on refresh either.

***Note:*** I had to put the `.SetItem` in an if statement cause, even tho the value was in storage it kept setting back the value to zero every time I refreshed the page. This was the way I found to stop that.

Comment: `window.localStorage`, or fire-off an AJAX/`fetch` request to a remote server.

Comment: A hint for you would be to use localStorage and listen to each input change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to set up a back end to send data to and save the information you want to keep stored, or save data in localStorage.

Just know it is not the best practice to save sensitive info in localStorage (as they can be compromised in cross-site scripting attacks).

localStorage.setItem puts a bit of data into localStorage (and that stays there till you clear it) and localStorage.getData extracts it.

This might help get you started on localStorage, but you will have to figure out the function to set the colour to the element you have.

```
let boxColour = localStorage.getItem("boxColour");

if (boxColour === null) {
  setBoxColour("colour");
} else {
  setBoxColour(boxColour);
}

function setBoxColour(colour){ localStorage.setItem("colour");}
```

/* Inside the function you have to get the item and change it's style attribute or add a class to add styles */

Careful with that localStorage data!

Comment: Thank you so much, it helped me a lot. About the data concerns, currently I'm just making pages on my own files without using connection to the internet.  You know, just one week in, messing around with html/css/js. But again, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `LocalStorage`.
It saves data in the page to be used after when the page is refreshed or closed and opened later.

Theres a example:

(Unfortunally, it seems to not work in the stackoverflow site, but if you try at your HTML file it will work)

```js
var loadFunc = (elem) => {
  console.log("Value saved is: "+ localStorage.getItem("savedValue"));
  
  if(localStorage.getItem("savedValue")){ //checks if value is saved or not
    elem.checked = localStorage.getItem("savedValue");
  }
}

var clickFunc = (elem) => {
  localStorage.setItem("savedValue", elem.checked); //set te value if in localStorage 
}
```

```html
Click the checkbox and the value will be saved.
<input type="checkbox" onload="loadFunc(this)" onclick="clickFunc(this)">
```